# android getDate from milliseconds stored in String field

Tags: java, android

I have a date stored in a `String` field in `SQLITE` with the String value

```
"/Date(1411472160000+0100)/"
```

how can I convert this back into a `date format` , the code below doesn't work. I think I need to convert from the milliseconds first but I cant see how to even get the above text into a long format first ?

any suggestions ?

```
Date convertedDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",         
java.util.Locale.getDefault());
convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);       
return dateFormat.format(convertedDate);
```

Comment: is that really the string? I mean, is "/Date" included?

Comment: yes the /date is included

Comment: For parsing you can use @AxelH's answer and to convert this parsed value to date object you can refer to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a *substring* from the `indexOf("(")` to the `indexOf("+")` and you should find the date in *milli*.

From there, I believe you can find the date ;)

```
   String s = "/Date(1411472160000+0100)/";
   s = s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1, s.indexOf("+"));
   Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(s));
```

With the same structure, you can find the `timezone (+0100) (from "+" to ")")` and work with a Calendar to find the right time for the right time area.

Comment: @Rachael M, yours accepted answer & your question direction refers to two different direction. However, its good to know that your problem is solved. Cheers :)

Comment: You are welcome. Ask to store the date in milli the next time and the time zone in an other field ;)

Comment: @ Amit K. Saha **I think I need to convert from the milliseconds first but I cant see how to even get the above text into a long format first ?**

Answer (score 3):

First you have to parse out the time value from String i.e. "1411472160000+0100" part.

Here in "1411472160000+0100" , "+0100" is the timezone info. If you don't want to consider the timezone, then you can take following approach.

Approach-1

```
long timestamp = 1245613885;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp * 1000);

int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

then to get the date in your specified format you can use-

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println(dateString); // 2009-06-21 15:51:25
```

Besides this approach, there is an excellent Java Date library called **JodaTime**.
If you want to incorporate the timezone info , you can refer to this constructor from JodaTime.

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-long-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-